# Solow Model: Steady state when there's population and technology growth

Tags: macroeconomics, solow

How is the steady state of a Solow Model defined when there's population growth and technological growth? The usual definition is to have $\dot{k} = 0$ (or $k_{t+1} = k_t$ in case of discrete time) and that would be equivalent to having $\dot{K} = 0$.

However, when there's population and technological growth, $$\dot{k} = 0 \rlap{\quad\not}\implies \dot{K} = 0.$$

Someone help me with the definition. Cite an article, paper or a book please.

Comment: In the case with population growth, $\dot{k}=0$ implies $\dot{\left(\frac{K}{N}\right)}=0$. Although the capital-labor ratio does not change in the steady state, the level of capital $K$ can grow with the same rate of growth as $N$.

Comment: @teddi Please post answers as answers; also OP asks for a reference.

Answer (score 4):

In the case of population growth, $\dot{k}=0$ implies $\dot{\left(\frac{K}{N}\right)}=0$. If $k=K/N$, then by taking logs
$$
 \ln k = \ln K - \ln N
$$
and differentiating w.r.t time
$$
\frac{\dot{k}}{k} = \frac{\dot{K}}{K} - \frac{\dot{N}}{N}
$$
At the steady state, the LHS = 0, so on the RHS, the growth rate of capital $\frac{\dot{K}}{K}$ must equal the growth rate of labor $\frac{\dot{N}}{N}$.

Although the capital-labor ratio $k$ does not change in the steady state, the level of capital $K$ expands at the same rate as the labor force $N$. This is called "capital widening".

Source: Jones C.I. "Introduction to economic growth" (1997) - page 25